# Using a shorter list as values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello I am trying to use a shorter list  as a value in a dictionary can anyone please help?

```
string = input("Input DNA Sequence: ")
sequence = [string[e:e+3] for e in range(0, len(string), 3)]
p_residue = list("WYS")
```

Input: TGGTACTCTTTCTTCACA
Output: {TGG:W,TAC:Y,TCT:S,TTC:W,TTC:Y,ACA:S}

I've tried cycle but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: when storing the data as a dictionary, the key `TTC` will get overwritten. That is not what the OP appears to want, as evidenced by the current output displayed, which shows the first sequence of `TTC` associated with `W` and the second sequence associated with `Y`. Can we get clarification on whether duplicates of any given trigram sequence are desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cycle` if you zip `p_residue` onto your sequence.

```
from itertools import cycle

def split_str_every(n, seq):
    return [seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]

def combine(seq, residue):
    return zip(sequence, cycle(p_residue))


sequence = split_str_every(3, "TGGTACTCTTTCTTCACA")
p_residue = ["W", "Y", "S"]

out = combine(sequence, p_residue)

print(dict(out))
```

Gives:

```
{'TGG': 'W', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TCT': 'S', 'TTC': 'Y', 'ACA': 'S'}
```

Which, as you can see, dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys by definition. We can use `defaultdics` to circumvent this problem. To fix this, we import `defaultdict` and redefine our combine function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def combine(seq, residue):
    zipped = zip(sequence, cycle(p_residue))
    ddict = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in zipped:
        ddict[k].append(v)

    return dict(ddict.items())

print(combine(sequence, p_residue))
```

Now gives the correct answer. Notice that the key `TTC` stores a list containing both `Y` & `W`:

```
{'TGG': ['W'], 'TAC': ['Y'], 'TCT': ['S'], 'TTC': ['W', 'Y'], 'ACA': ['S']}
```

Comment: See my comment above (on the OP's post) about the fact that dicts will overwrite a given key and whether the OP wants to have duplicate keys. If that is the case, then storing the content in a dictionary will likely not be possible and we may need clarification on what might constitute a reasonable solution to the OP.

Comment: @E.Ducateme I noticed, I'm working on using defaultdicts to avoid this problem.

Comment: You guys/gals are right! Dictionary was a bad way to proceed with this problem. I switched to a list then used map() and cycle to combine the two. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RT90 no problem! You can post your own solution to the question,I’m curious as to how you used map!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sequence = {
    string[e:e+3]: p_residue[(e//3) % len(p_residue)]
    for e in range(0, len(string), 3)
}
```

Output

```
{'TGG': 'W', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TCT': 'S', 'TTC': 'Y', 'ACA': 'S'}
```

To understand better,

`e` is one of `[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]`

`e//3` is integer division, so, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

`(e//3) % 3` is to keep it to residue length, so, `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`

This mathematical approach induces a cycle